# About Database access in Yii

Tags: php, database, yii

What is the difference between

```
TableA::model()->getDbConnection();
```

and

```
TableB::model()->getDbConnection();
```

or they are both equivalent to

```
Yii::app()->db;
```

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, I think they are just the same, since usually there is a single database connection for all the records in application. For `TableA::model()->getDbConnection` If dbconnection of the record is defined, that connection will be returned, otherwise default dbconnection of app will be returned which is defined in /protected/config/main.php. You can refer to [source code](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.8/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#603) or [multiple databases support in yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/123/multiple-database-support-in-yii/).

Comment: +1 for 'refer to source code', so many people seam to forget that open source means you can actually see whats going on